# skiplist- i really need an explanation ,how does it insert and delete

Tags: data-structures, skip-lists

i really dont understand the probabilty thing of this list. in addition to the statement"we have to examine no more than n/2 + 1 nodes (where n is the length of the list).Also giving every fourth node a pointer four ahead (Figure1c) requires that no more than n/4 + 2 nodes be examined".
this statement i read in the following link:ftp://ftp.cs.umd.edu/pub/skipLists/skiplists.pdf

Comment: I am guessing this is homework-related matter. Can you make your question clearer ?

Comment: actually it is not a homework, i just missed the lec and im trying to understand the benefits of skip-list especially how does it insert and delete

Comment: i read that statement in a paper of skip-list.

Comment: i just need the concept,,, not implementation

Comment: If you missed a lecture and are trying to catch up, that's still homework.

Comment: The [original paper](ftp://ftp.cs.umd.edu/pub/skipLists/skiplists.pdf) explains it very well.

Answer (score 3):

What you're not understanding is that *every* node has a link at level 1. That is, at the lowest level, the data structure is essentially a linked list. Searching for a node using this is of course an O(n) operation.

Each node of the skip list has *at least* one link: the one at level 1. *On average*, half of the nodes also have a link at level 2. If this was the highest level at which a link existed, then you could find an arbitrary node in O(n/2). Basically, you follow the 2nd level nodes until either you find the item you're looking for, or until you get to a node whose value is larger than the one you're looking for. At that point, you step down to the level 1 nodes and search forward from the previous node (i.e. the one that's less than the one you're looking for).

Again on average, 1/4 of the nodes have a link at level 3. Using these, you can find an arbitrary node in O(n/4). You first search the level 3 nodes until you either find the node or go past it, then drop down to the level 2 nodes from that point, and to the level 1 nodes if don't find the node at level 2.

If you follow the math, you can see that if your maximum level is `m`, then as long as you have less than `2^m` nodes in the skip list, your amortized average search time will be O(log2(n)), where `n` is the number of items in the list.

So the structure of a skip list node is like this:

```
SkiplistNode
{
    int level;
    SomeType data; // the data held in the node
    SkiplistNode* forwards[]; // an array of 'level' forward references
}
```

If a node has a `level` value of 1, then there will be just one item in the `forwards` array. If it's at level 4, then there will be four entries: one for each of levels 4, 3, 2, and 1.

As it turns out, the *average* size of the `forwards` array is 2. That follows the progression `1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16, + 1/32, ...` That is:

```
Every node has a link at level 1
1/2 of the nodes have a link at level 2
1/4 of the nodes have a link at level 3
1/8 of the nodes have a link at level 4
etc.
```

Is that more clear now?

Answer (score 2):

Skip lists are explained quite well in their [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). If you have a specific question about the data structure itself feel free to ask them though.

Comment: thanks 4 ur help.  i have problems with the insertion and deletion functions im trying to understand them especially the part of getting random level

Answer (score 1):

Lecture from MIT about skip lists: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-6710586843601387849#

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat easier to understand explanation can be found here : http://igoro.com/archive/skip-lists-are-fascinating/